# Is there a terminal emulator with text-editor like features?

Tags: ide, editor, emulator, text

> This question was asked in superuser, I wrote an answer but it got closed as off topic.

Is there a terminal emulator where I can `Shift` + `Left` to select a part of the text and then `Ctrl` + `C` to copy?

This is common in some text-editors, IDEs, but something I've been struggling to achieve when working with command lines.

Asked by: Márcio Carôso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "Vim mode" for some terminals, like `URxvT`.

---

Or you could try using bash with:

`et -o vi` or `set -o emacs`

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/set-o-vi-emacs

Emacs Mode

> `$ set -o emacs`
>
> This is usually the default editing mode when in the bash environment and means that you are able to use commands like those in Emacs (defined in the >Readline library) to move the cursor, cut and paste text, or undo editing.
> Commands to take advantage of bash's Emacs Mode:
>
> - ctrl-a Move cursor to beginning of line
> - ctrl-e Move cursor to end of line
> - meta-b Move cursor back one word
> - meta-f Move cursor forward one word
> - ctrl-w Cut the last word
> - ctrl-u Cut everything before the cursor
> - ctrl-k Cut everything after the cursor
> - ctrl-y Paste the last thing to be cut
> - ctrl-_ Undo
>   NOTE: ctrl- = hold control, meta- = hold meta (where meta is usually the alt or escape key).
>
> A combination of ctrl-u to cut the line combined with ctrl-y can be very helpful. If you are in middle of typing a command and need to return to the prompt to retrieve more information you can use ctrl-u to save what you have typed in and after you retrieve the needed information ctrl-y will recover what was cut.

Vi Mode

> `$ set -o vi`
>
> Vi mode allows for the use of vi like commands when at the bash prompt. When set to this mode initially you will be in insert mode (be able to type at the prompt unlike when you enter vi). Hitting the escape key takes you into >command mode.
> Commands to take advantage of bash's Vi Mode:
>
> - h Move cursor left
> - l Move cursor right
> - A Move cursor to end of line and put in insert mode
> - 0 (zero) Move cursor to beginning of line (doesn't put in insert mode)
> - i Put into insert mode at current position
> - a Put into insert mode after current position
> - dd Delete line (saved for pasting)
> - D Delete text after current cursor position (saved for pasting)
> - p Paste text that was deleted
> - j Move up through history commands
> - k Move down through history commands
> - u Undo

---

Im pretty sure, that you could "hack" emacs to do whatever you want it to do:

GNU Emacs: An extensible, customizable, free/libre text editor — and more.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/

> https://opensource.com/resources/what-emacs
>
> Emacs is a text editor designed for POSIX operating systems and available on Linux, BSD, macOS, Windows, and more. Users love Emacs because it features efficient commands for common but complex actions and for the plugins and configuration hacks that have developed around it for nearly 40 years.
>
> Because it's an old editor that was developed well before modern computer conventions and terminology existed (for instance, you "visit" instead of "opening" a file, and you "write" instead of "save," and so on), Emacs is often viewed as complex and even mysterious. As time has shown, however, once you learn the basics, you have a powerful, efficient, and extremely hackable editor for life.

---

Kate text editor has vi mode and can open a terminal. I did not test if vi mode works in embedded termial.

```
Settings → Configure Kate… → Editing → VI Input Mode.
```